# Connecting to Facebook with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, facebook, authentication, connect

I'm wondering if there is a way to connect to Facebook using VB.net? By connect I mean I would be able to access friend list, notifications, messages etc.

So far I have managed to validate the log in - i.e. it tells you if a user exists with the specified details. But now I'm stuck with how to view the accounts information.

Thanks

Comment: FB uses OAuth I believe.  You need to study that API   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0

Comment: @Andrew it seems you are new to SO, if the answer provided has helped please checked the check mark by my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get an AppKey, this is required. Another thing is you have to install the sdk from Facebook.  After this has been done, take a look at this project to get going, its too broad to post here...

https://github.com/prabirshrestha/FB-CSharp-SDK-First-FB-Application

https://developers.facebook.com

Good Luck!